# 500 internal server error in php with IIS server.....?

Tags: php

I am getting 
"500 internal server error in php "  when i execute the below code.
When i removed this Part `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` of my below code . The entire code excecutes properl. If i add this `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` function again, It is not working.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startTime = new Date();   
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){    
        var endTime = new Date();       
        var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);     
        var xmlhttp;       
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)       
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();       
        }
        else        
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Compaq.XMLHTTP");        
        }
         var filename = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>";
         var fullurl= "<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>";
         var  subid= "<?php echo $_GET['domain_id'] ?>";
         var  kw= "<?php echo $_GET['target'] ?>";
         var ref = "<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];?>";
                  var ip = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>";
                   var countryCode = "<?php echo $countryCode;?>";
            var countryName = "<?php echo $countryName;?>";
              var  regionName = "<?php echo $regionName;?>";
                var cityName = "<?php echo  $cityName;?>";
                  var zipCode = "<?php echo $zipCode;?>";
                    var areacode = "<?php echo $areacode;?>";

         var url = "time_on_site.php?time="+timeSpent+"&filename="+filename+"&fullurl="+fullurl+"&subid="+subid+"&ref="+ref+"&ip="+ip+"&countryCode="+countryCode+"&countryName="+countryName+"&regionName="+regionName+"&cityName="+cityName+"&zipCode="+zipCode+"&areacode="+areacode+"&kw="+kw;
         xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);        
         xmlhttp.send(null);     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check your server error logs. A 500 error will almost always mean there's something more specific in the logs. I'd guess it's because there's no referer, but I don't know what your particular server configuration will do in that case.

Comment: Please post the actual code that's getting the error. You're probably not removing the line properly, so you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Barmar, When i am using "$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];" this function only  getting error in IIS server but i have checked different server it's working fine. I have tried lot.  Please give me idea so i can fix this issue.

Comment: @Hara Prasad, code seems to run fine on mine, like Barmar said there's probably a syntax error, try single quotes instead of double? 

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: @wolfgang, I have tried this way but i m getting same error

Comment: try re-writing the code from a no-error point, in this case starting from var ref = "<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];?>"; and working yourself to completion